# Status bar is landscape after rotation in only portrait view

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I have allowed all viewControllers in my swift application to be in portrait mode. I did this programatically, because some viewControllers contain videos that I want to be played in both, landscape and portrait mode. My problem is that when I rotate the device, the view stays in the portrait mode (that's what I want) but the status bar of the device is shown in landscape mode.

This is the code in **Swift 3** that I have added to make the view in the only portrait mode:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

Any help please?

**Edit:**
On my AppDelegate I specified my initial view:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Then in my firstViewController I can go to another view via a button click like this:

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
        self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Or I show some details in a child view (that is opened after a button click):

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailViewController") as! DetailViewController
addChildViewController(vc)
view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Are you using multiple windows in your app? the video viewController might be in a non key window.

Comment: Can you please explain me what do you mean by multiple windows?

Comment: UIWindow how the UI have been done programmatically or via storyboard ?

Comment: I used the storyboard to create my views then I present the views programmatically.

Comment: I have at first an uiviewcontroller then I present or addChild to it after some actions

Comment: posting more code will help i cant tell what happening

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: you should not set the root view controller it is set automatically unless you changed **Main storyboard file base name** in Info.plist nor creating the window by yourself since its all handled by storyboard

Comment: also are you calling this: self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil) before **viewDidAppear** ?

Comment: For the self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil) no it in an IBAction function. For the root view controller must I set the initial view controller from the storyboard? Because when I begin the creation of the views controllers I added another one (the firstViewController) but I leave the default one as the initial view controller on the storyboard. Have I to delete the default one and make the firstViewController the initial one from the storyboard?

Comment: what is you app default orientation? landscape or portrait

Comment: From the Info.plist I have in item 0: "Portrait (bottom home button)", Item 2: "Landscape (right home button)" and item 3: "Landscape (left home button)".

Comment: so **shouldAutorotate** should be in the rootViewController

Comment: So in my case in the default view controller(that is the initial view in the storyboard) not in the first view controller that I had set in the AppDelegate. Isn't is?

Comment: Have I to put it only in the root view and it will have effect in all the views of my app? Because I added it in all views

Comment: Only the root if you won't to force it

Comment: It works! Thanks lot!! Can you please make it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**shouldAutorotate** should be in the rootViewController because the top viewController will fore it to all of its sub controllers